# how to set an ether value as a function parameter?

Tags: transactions, payments, transfer

I work on Truffle and my project is simple. `contract A` should transfer some ether to `contract B`. `contract A` is funded enough. In `contract A`, there is a function called `payment` that performs the transfer and `uint val` is its parameter that tells the function the ether value to transfer. Whenever i try the function in Truffle console the following error occurs:

`Error: invalid number value (arg="val", coderType="uint256", value=1000000000000000000)`

I don't know how to assign a correct value as an argument to `payment` function.

contract A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract A{

    event Payment(address receiver, uint value);

    function payment(uint val) public payable returns(string memory){
        address(uint160(0xae1b77270ae418bDd72e14e842F57D9EC2DBD1d8)).transfer(val);\\Transfer to contract B
        emit Payment(0xae1b77270ae418bDd72e14e842F57D9EC2DBD1d8, val);
        return "Payment done successfully";
    }

    function() external payable{}
}
```

contract B:

```
contract B{
    function balanceView() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;           
    }

    function() external payable{}
}
```

The command i tried in Truffle console:

```
truffle(develop)> A.deployed().then(function(ins){app=ins})
undefined
truffle(develop)> app.payment.sendTransaction(1000000000000000000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
sendTransaction(1000000000000000000)
```

To this:

```
sendTransaction({value: '1000000000000000000'})
```

Comment: Actually, shouldn't it be `val` instead of `value` ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain: No, it shouldn't. You're probably looking at function `payment`, which has nothing to do with all of this. And in any case, the names of input parameters in contract functions have no impact or meaning when you call those functions from an off-chain script (or from anywhere else for that matter).

Comment: @goodvibration: Thanks for your answer. It worked. Just a thing: if i want to set the recipient address as an argument in `.sendTransaction(...)` what shouls i do? As i realized `payment` does not need a corresponding parameter for that. Am i right?

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: You're welcome. What do you mean by "recipient"?

Comment: @goodvibration: I mean i want to type the address of `contract B` in  `.sendTransaction(...)`  on Truffle console instead i use `address(uint160(0xae1b77270ae418bDd72e14e842F57D9EC2DBD1d8)).transfer(val)` in `contract A` file.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: You should take it as an argument in function `payment`. In order to pass that argument to the function, you should change `app.payment` to something like `app.payment('0xae1b...')`. BTW, I noticed that in function `payment`, you should get rid of the `val` argument, and then use `msg.value` instead.

Comment: @goodvibration: Thanks for your help but by this command i got the solution: `app.payment.sendTransaction('0xae1b77270ae418bDd72e14e842F57D9EC2DBD1d8', {value:'1000000000000000000'})`. I replaced `uint val` with `address recipient` in the function parameter.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: Your question was how to pass ether value, not anything else. And on that one I have answered. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` of JavaScript. As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) ,the `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant has a value of `9007199254740991` (`9,007,199,254,740,991` or `~9` quadrillion). The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers. It can only safely represent integers between -(2^53 - 1) and (2^53 - 1). alongside that, you use `uint` and you can't use the negative section of this interval. Thus, you are restricted more. You can solve that via:

1. Pass a number non-out-of the `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` .
2. As @goodvibration answered, removed `.payment()` argument and pass your given value with `.sendTransaction({value:<value>})`.

Comment: An EVM `uint` is by default 256 bits in size. The biggest number is therefore (2^256)-1, which is 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935.

Comment: What is happening in the question is that it's hitting the Javascript MAX_SAFE_INTEGER limit, which is 9007199254740991. 1000000000000000000 is above this limit, so `value` must be passed as a string, not an integer.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Thanks for your pointing. I altered the answer by your guide. Please check it.

Comment: Yep, that looks good. However, your recommendation in point 1) would restrict the user to passing values below MAX_SAFE_INTEGER into the contract, even though the contract supports much higher numbers. When considering wei values, 1 ETH has 18 decimal places :-) The way around this is to pass the large integer as a string. (This is what the code in the accepted answer is doing - notice the `'` around the value.)